# How do I create a link to a file on a network share in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an MVC3 web application.  One of my requirements is that I have a link to help documentation.  Here the help documents are in Microsoft Word (.doc) and stored on a network share. I have tried a wide variety of things to attempt to create a link to this document but I am having little success.

Presently, the link is in a view call Help, it specifically /Home/Help.

I can create a link, but it adds the /Home/ routing to the beginning of the URL.  I've attempt to create a ignore rule with no success.

Anyone have any suggestions?  Keep in mind the location of files is not a requirement I can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use an ActionLink to the ControllerAction like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Home")
```

and implement the Download Action like this:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    return new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("\\\\myserver\\pub\\test.doc"), "application/msword");
}
```

but you should only use this if your doc is very small...